# Obtain an HTML element's positon in body coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a nested HTML element called Div1 (a div that sits inside another div & that other div sits inside the body), **how can I get Div1's x,y position from the body elements perspective** maybe this is called window/screen position of a HTML element)?

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

```
function getWhere(node, top){
    top= top || document.body;
    var x= 0, y= 0;
    while(node){
        y+= node.offsetTop;
        x+= node.offsetLeft;
        node= node.offsetParent;
        if(node== top) break;
    }
    return [x, y];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use offset to get the position relative to the document.

```
$(element).offset();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/offset

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this with pure js.

Comment: Do the downvoter: I realize, the OP's question didn't specifically mention jQuery, but how is this not a valid suggestion?

Comment: Because it can be regarded as proselytizing. I personally do not care when a jQuery answer is posted on a non-jQuery question, but a certain percentage of SO users will react negatively to it.